# Laravel form validation doesn't recognize text input the first time, but it does the second time

Tags: php, laravel, validation, parsley

Whenever I go to submit the form, the bio textarea returns the form validation saying, "This is required," when it already has text typed into it already. When I press the submit button a second time(without changing anything), then it works.

```
 {!! Form::open(['route' => 'bios.store', 'data-parsley-validate' => '', 'files' => true]) !!}

                {{ Form::label('image', 'Upload Image (Less than 2 MB):') }}
                {{ Form::file('image') }} <br/>

                {{ Form::label('bio', 'Bio') }}
                {{ Form::textarea('bio', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '', 'maxlength' => '191']) }} <br/>

                {{ Form::label('city', 'City') }}
                {{ Form::text('city', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '', 'maxlength' => '191']) }}<br/>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                {{ Form::label('state', 'State') }}
                {{ Form::select('state',[
                    'States' => [
                                    null => 'Please Select',
                                    'AL' => 'Alabama',
                                    'AK' => 'Alaska',
                                    'AZ' => 'Arizona',
                                    'AR' => 'Arkansas',
                                    'CA' => 'California',
                                    'CO' => 'Colorado',
                                    'CT' => 'Connecticut',
                                    'DE' => 'Delaware',
                                    'DC' => 'District Of Columbia',
                                    'FL' => 'Florida',
                                    'GA' => 'Georgia',
                                    'HI' => 'Hawaii',
                                    'ID' => 'Idaho',
                                    'IL' => 'Illinois',
                                    'IN' => 'Indiana',
                                    'IA' => 'Iowa',
                                    'KS' => 'Kansas',
                                    'KY' => 'Kentucky',
                                    'LA' => 'Louisiana',
                                    'ME' => 'Maine',
                                    'MD' => 'Maryland',
                                    'MA' => 'Massachusetts',
                                    'MI' => 'Michigan',
                                    'MN' => 'Minnesota',
                                    'MS' => 'Mississippi',
                                    'MO' => 'Missouri',
                                    'MT' => 'Montana',
                                    'NE' => 'Nebraska',
                                    'NV' => 'Nevada',
                                    'NH' => 'New Hampshire',
                                    'NJ' => 'New Jersey',
                                    'NM' => 'New Mexico',
                                    'NY' => 'New York',
                                    'NC' => 'North Carolina',
                                    'ND' => 'North Dakota',
                                    'OH' => 'Ohio',
                                    'OK' => 'Oklahoma',
                                    'OR' => 'Oregon',
                                    'PA' => 'Pennsylvania',
                                    'RI' => 'Rhode Island',
                                    'SC' => 'South Carolina',
                                    'SD' => 'South Dakota',
                                    'TN' => 'Tennessee',
                                    'TX' => 'Texas',
                                    'UT' => 'Utah',
                                    'VT' => 'Vermont',
                                    'VA' => 'Virginia',
                                    'WA' => 'Washington',
                                    'WV' => 'West Virginia',
                                    'WI' => 'Wisconsin',
                                    'WY' => 'Wyoming',
                                ],
                ], null, ['required']) }}
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6"">
                {{ Form::label('identity', 'Role') }}
                {{ Form::select('identity',[
                    'Identity' => [
                                    null => 'Please Select',
                                    'Athlete' => 'Athlete',
                                    'Coach' => 'Trainer',
                                ],
                ], null, ['required']) }}
                <br/><br/>
                </div>
                {{ Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block']) }}
                <br/>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Here is the whole file.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', '| Bio')

@section('stylesheets')
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/homie.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endsection

@section('scripts')
 {!! Html::script('assets/js/parsley.min.js') !!}
    <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=rmgyrwthrrr2h5weft0b1mllmieqrg3hmdrsg58sym44ure3"></script>
    <script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        plugins: 'link',
        menubar: false
        });
    </script>
@endsection

@section('navbar')
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <h4 class="icon-style"><img src="{{ URL::asset('assets/images/etp.png') }}" alt="No image found" height="45px" width="45px">
                    <a class="icon-link" href="home">Elite Training Pro</a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8  col-md-offset-2">
            <h3>Tell Us About Yourself</h3>
            <hr>
                {!! Form::open(['route' => 'bios.store', 'data-parsley-validate' => '', 'files' => true]) !!}

                {{ Form::label('image', 'Upload Image (Less than 2 MB):') }}
                {{ Form::file('image') }} <br/>

                {{ Form::label('bio', 'Bio') }}
                {{ Form::textarea('bio', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '', 'maxlength' => '191']) }} <br/>

                {{ Form::label('city', 'City') }}
                {{ Form::text('city', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '', 'maxlength' => '191']) }}<br/>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                {{ Form::label('state', 'State') }}
                {{ Form::select('state',[
                    'States' => [
                                    null => 'Please Select',
                                    'AL' => 'Alabama',
                                    'AK' => 'Alaska',
                                    'AZ' => 'Arizona',
                                    'AR' => 'Arkansas',
                                    'CA' => 'California',
                                    'CO' => 'Colorado',
                                    'CT' => 'Connecticut',
                                    'DE' => 'Delaware',
                                    'DC' => 'District Of Columbia',
                                    'FL' => 'Florida',
                                    'GA' => 'Georgia',
                                    'HI' => 'Hawaii',
                                    'ID' => 'Idaho',
                                    'IL' => 'Illinois',
                                    'IN' => 'Indiana',
                                    'IA' => 'Iowa',
                                    'KS' => 'Kansas',
                                    'KY' => 'Kentucky',
                                    'LA' => 'Louisiana',
                                    'ME' => 'Maine',
                                    'MD' => 'Maryland',
                                    'MA' => 'Massachusetts',
                                    'MI' => 'Michigan',
                                    'MN' => 'Minnesota',
                                    'MS' => 'Mississippi',
                                    'MO' => 'Missouri',
                                    'MT' => 'Montana',
                                    'NE' => 'Nebraska',
                                    'NV' => 'Nevada',
                                    'NH' => 'New Hampshire',
                                    'NJ' => 'New Jersey',
                                    'NM' => 'New Mexico',
                                    'NY' => 'New York',
                                    'NC' => 'North Carolina',
                                    'ND' => 'North Dakota',
                                    'OH' => 'Ohio',
                                    'OK' => 'Oklahoma',
                                    'OR' => 'Oregon',
                                    'PA' => 'Pennsylvania',
                                    'RI' => 'Rhode Island',
                                    'SC' => 'South Carolina',
                                    'SD' => 'South Dakota',
                                    'TN' => 'Tennessee',
                                    'TX' => 'Texas',
                                    'UT' => 'Utah',
                                    'VT' => 'Vermont',
                                    'VA' => 'Virginia',
                                    'WA' => 'Washington',
                                    'WV' => 'West Virginia',
                                    'WI' => 'Wisconsin',
                                    'WY' => 'Wyoming',
                                ],
                ], null, ['required']) }}
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6"">
                {{ Form::label('identity', 'Role') }}
                {{ Form::select('identity',[
                    'Identity' => [
                                    null => 'Please Select',
                                    'Athlete' => 'Athlete',
                                    'Coach' => 'Trainer',
                                ],
                ], null, ['required']) }}
                <br/><br/>
                </div>
                {{ Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block']) }}
                <br/>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE saves content to textarea on form submit. You have to manually trigger save on TinyMCE before form submit or trigger it automatically on input change.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    plugins: 'link',
    menubar: false,
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            tinymce.triggerSave();
        });
    }
});
```